# MVC3 edit a data entry based on another

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, edit

in my app i want to change class from first to second for example but depending on the data entry of the grade .

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Class)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Class, new SelectList(new[] { "1st grade", "2nd grade", "3rd grade" }))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Class)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.grade)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.grade)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.grade)
    </div>
```

Comment: So based on the value in the `grade` textbox you want to select different option in the `class` dropdown list?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want @QuetiM.Porta